# Increase screen width for responsive navigation bar display

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to increase the screen width at which the responsive navigation bar kicks in for my website. I have pasted the original codes for my navigation bar in JSFiddle.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/zvumyx1e/#&togetherjs=V618c4byhE

So I changed the media screen query screen size for max-width 767 to max-width 1024 in css code to make the responsive navbar toggle display at tablet screen size. The original code is below and the only change I made was the value '767' to '1024'. The full code is in the css portion of the JSFiddle.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

.shop_isle_banners_section .widget {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    width: 44px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar-header {
    display: table !important;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}
.shop_isle_header_title {
    margin-left: 0;
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.header-container {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-header {
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

/* Navbar */

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
}
```

This actually made the toggle bar display but there are issues:

1. The navigation bar does not collapse when clicked; and
2. There's space between the navigation toggle and the menu items.

I'll really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: what's the problem? What's happening?

Comment: I basically want the toggle bar which is displayed in responsive mode when the site is viewed on mobile phone screen sizes to also be displayed on tablet screen sizes, while the regular laptop and desktop screens display the full-width none responsive menu bar.

Comment: is this custom css you create or it along with theme ??

Comment: look like your wordpress site use bootstrap as front-end

Comment: Hi @Mostafa Baezid, the custom css came along with the theme. And yes, it does use bootstrap from reading up on it. I'm using a child theme but the code is copied from the parent theme.

Comment: is your site is live ?? or can you tell me the theme name ?

Comment: Hi Mostafa, not yet live but the theme name is ShopIsle

Comment: @MostafaBaezid I have edited the question and hoping you can assist. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will look after it. One que do you properly add bootstrap files in your child theme??

Comment: @MostafaBaezid I really appreciate. And no I didn't add bootstrap files, I only copied the style css and functions.php files into the child theme.

Comment: i think the problem is import the parent theme files is not correct. because bootstrap always comes with responsive. so when you create a child theme you need to import the parent files correctly. Read this two article for better understanding  [ https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes ] & [ http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/ ]

Comment: @MostafaBaezid I read the two links you sent and none of them mention bootstrap files. I created the child theme using the theme developers' instructions which require copying only style.css and functions.php files into the child theme folder. You can view the site at afriartistry(dot)com if it will help you understand the navigation bar issue. Thank you.

Comment: @veesilouette as I see all other pages looks good on mobile view. Only the landing page create problem.

Comment: @MostafaBaezid yes but that is because of a font changing plugin. I am sorry I have been working on the site you might not have seen the actual issue. Please check now by looking at the menu bar, click and you will see the menu items are not collapsing.

Comment: @veesilouette I think issue is something else. Coz your nav is ok . See the fiddle [ https://jsfiddle.net/yfrqdyLv/#&togetherjs=M7QiEo8DLp ] see the jQuery part it will help you to make onclick collapse

Comment: I am using the child theme. I copied the jQuery from the parent theme's files, the css from the parent theme also while the html came from page source browser inspection.  The child theme borrows the parent theme's attributes so I expected that these scripts should run in the child theme?

Comment: @veesilouette child theme allows you change the functionality of the parent theme. But why all you child theme style.css is empty. I recommend re-create the child theme properly.  I see all the custom css in your parent style.css then what is the benefits of creating child theme .

Comment: Hi @MostafaBaezid, I'm really new to all this so don't know what to do. I followed the theme developer's instruction for creating child theme here: http://docs.themeisle.com/article/14-how-to-create-a-child-theme everything seems to work fine in the child theme as it is. It is only this issue that's not working. Please how do I create it properly. Thank you so much for all your help. I will really appreciate if we can sort out the code issue. I can see that it is running now in the jsFiddle but I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125642/discussion-between-mostafa-baezid-and-veesilouette).

Comment: @veesilouette sorry for late reply. I see you already solve the problem. Actually I  also solve it out. good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

I'm not sure if these are the elements you want to resize and if there not, change the `.navbar-custom` or the `.navbar-nav` If you want to resize more than just two, copy and past the code over again.

```
.navbar-custom {
width: 235px;
padding-left:30px
}

.navbar-nav {
float: right; 
width: 235px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}
```

This goes at the bottom of your main CSS btw.

Comment: Thanks @Dove Man, but it didn't work. That just aligned the desktop view menu items (which are displayed in horizontal layout) to the right instead of changing the menu display to mobile responsive menu which I showed in the first picture attached.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/tjbaezid/0gFbs8lzBX) This is the demo I also comment out on the css from where the media query will be need in your wordpress custom css only for wordpress.
Here is also the part of css - I have alre

```
/* From bottom we can use this in our custom css file for media query (navbar-toggle- 1024px) */

.navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0; 
    }
.navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .container{
     width:100%;  
   }
  .navbar-header {
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}

  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    width: 44px;
    cursor: pointer;

}


 .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1201;
    }

    .navbar-nav li {
    position: relative;
    float:none !important;
    margin-left:-15px; 
    margin-right:15px;
   }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block !important;
    padding: 10px 15px;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(73, 71, 71, 0.15) !important;
}
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }


    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```